# Symbolic links in libzip

Tags: c++, linux, symlink, libzip

I'm using libzip in a c++ application for Linux that will need to be able to zip/unzip directories containing symbolic links. I want to add the link itself without following it. Reading out the link with readlink() and adding it to the zip archive results in a nonsense standard file when unzipped with unzip.

Solution does not need to be portable, it will only be used under Linux. The linux zip command has a --symlinks flags so the zip standard should support it. System calls are not really an option, the number of files is quite large and this makes the application extremely slow.

Is it possible to add symlinks with libzip, and how?

Thanks,
Sander

Comment: Why don't you use [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29)??

Comment: Tar is unfortunately not an option for compatibility reasons. We have to work with a third-party piece of software later on.

Comment: To have a symlink inside a ZIP archive, there should be an "ASi extra block for Unix" that contains the 16-bit "Mode" field with  S_IFLNK bit set. Although a different library, but you may get an idea here, there is also a Python script to create .zip archives with arbitrary symlinks: stackoverflow.com/a/65817451/6910868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on documentation: no

According to its [webpage](http://www.nih.at/libzip/README.html), libzip is based on [zlib](http://zlib.net/).  The zip program used in Linux, etc, is [info-zip](http://www.info-zip.org/), which does not use zlib, but is self-contained (and contains features not in zlib).

Comment: Right, I already saw that zip/unzip do not depend on libzip - the point I wanted to prove is just that you _can_ have symlinks in a .zip file (because linux "zip" command creates them). Otherwise I am using linux "unzip" command just for testing the created archive now.

Comment: The [source code](http://www.nih.at/libzip/) for libzip does not mention symbolic links, so it is not supported.  That was the question which was asked.

Comment: Sorry, misread that. I had read the documentation - but there is too much unclarity for me about zip_source_t, the structure of a .zip archive and the structure of a symlink to conclude that it's not possible just because of the libzip documentation.

Comment: The zip program has some features (such as VMS attributes -- and symlinks) which apply only to certain platforms.  libzip does not include those features, providing the *common* features available across all platforms.  If it had some special feature, there would be a function call to manipulate it.  (But reading the source code helps).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

Below a function i use for zipping a list of files in c-code.
The files to zip are stored in a cJSON struct,no uid/gid set and files/directories relative to a directory "base" (as that is my appliction).

The Function returns 0 on success.

```
int list_zip_it(char * upload_zip_name,char * base, cJSON * filelist)
{
   int result=0;
   int error_n = 0;
   struct zip *archive = zip_open(upload_zip_name, ZIP_TRUNCATE | ZIP_CREATE, &error_n);
   if(!archive)
   {
     printf(stderr,"could not open or create archive\n");
     return -1;
   }
   mode_t mode=0;
   cJSON * item;
   cJSON_ArrayForEach(item,filelist)
   {
      char * path=NULL; 
      path=item->valuestring;

      // stat the item
      struct stat sb;
      if (stat(path, &sb) == 0 ) mode=sb.st_mode;
      zip_uint32_t attr=0;
      attr=((mode ) << 16L);

      char rel_file[1024];
      if (strncmp(path,CI_PROJECT_DIR,strlen(base))==0 )
      {
          snprintf(rel_file,1024,"%s",path+strlen(base)+1);
          printf("archive filename: %s\n",rel_file);
      } 
      else
      {
         fprintf(stderr,"filename outside base-derectory\n");
         continue;
      }
      if (S_ISDIR(mode))
      {
        int index = (int)zip_add_dir(archive, rel_file);
        if (index>0) zip_file_set_external_attributes(archive, index, 0, ZIP_OPSYS_UNIX, attr);
      }
      else if (S_ISLNK(mode)) // symlink
      {
        char link[1024];//=calloc(1, 1024);
        memset(link, 0, 1024);
        ssize_t size_link=readlink(path , link, 1023);
        if (size_link > 0)
        {
            struct zip_source *source = zip_source_buffer(archive , link, ( zip_uint64_t)size_link,0);
            if (source)
            {
                int index = (int)zip_add(archive, rel_file, source);
                if (index>0) zip_file_set_external_attributes(archive, index, 0, ZIP_OPSYS_UNIX, attr);
             }
             else
             {
                printf(stderr,"failed to create source buffer: %s \n", zip_strerror(archive) );
                zip_source_free(source);
             }
           }
           else error("failed to read link: %s \n",path );
       }
       else if (S_ISREG(mode))
       {
         struct zip_source *source = zip_source_file(archive, path, 0, 0);
         if(source == NULL)
         {
             error("failed to create source buffer: %s \n", zip_strerror(archive) );
             result=1;
             break;
          }
          // todo calculate filename relative to project_dir
          int index = (int)zip_add(archive, rel_file, source);
          if(index < 0 )
          {
              int zep,sep;
              zip_error_get(archive, &zep, &sep);
              if (zep== ZIP_ER_EXISTS )
              {
                  fprintf(stderr,"failed to add file to archive: %s \n", zip_strerror(archive) );
                  zip_source_free(source);
              }
              else
              {
                 fprintf(stderr,"failed to add file to archive: %s \n", zip_strerror(archive) );
                 zip_source_free(source);
                 result=1;
                 break;
               }
           }
           else
           {
                zip_file_set_external_attributes(archive, index, 0, ZIP_OPSYS_UNIX, attr);
           }
        }
    }
    zip_close(archive);
    return result;
}
```